# AngularJS filtering using <tr> tag not working

Tags: angularjs, filter, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am rather new to AngularJS and I am trying to using ng-repeat to display out the modules that are available in my school. Moreover, trying to use the filter function to filter out the modules(both ModuleCode and ModuleTitle) through the textbox. However, after hours of trying, I fail to do it :C. Is there anyone out there to guide me on how to filter my data?

```
angular.forEach(moduleList, function(value,key){
            $scope.modList.push({
                ModuleCode      : moduleList[key].ModuleCode,
                ModuleTitle     : moduleList[key].ModuleTitle,
                Semesters       : moduleList[key].Semesters
            });
});

<rd-widget>
        <rd-widget-header icon="fa-search" title="Module Search">

            <input type="text" ng-model = "searchBox" placeholder="Search" class="form-control input-md" ng-keypress="test($event)"/>
            <p>{{searchBox}}</p>
        </rd-widget-header>
        <rd-widget-body classes="medium no-padding">
            <div class="table-responsive">

                <table class="table fixed-header">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center" data-ng-click="orderBy('ModuleCode')">Module Code</th>
                            <th class="text-center"  data-ng-click="orderBy('ModuleTitle')">Module Name</th>
                            <th class="text-center" data-ng-click="orderBy('Semesters')">Semester</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                       <tr data-ng-repeat = "modules in modList | filter:filterMod">
                           <td class="text-center">{{modules.ModuleCode}}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{modules.ModuleTitle}}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{modules.Semesters}}</td>

                       </tr>


                    </tbody>
                </table> 
            </div>
        </rd-widget-body>
    <rd-widget>

        $scope.filterMod = function(module){
    if(!$scope.searchBox || module.ModuleCode.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchBox) != -1){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Well, what's `filterMod`?

Comment: I have updated the code. It is at the btm. I don't think it work was trying to filter through custom filter function

Answer (score 0):

Just change

**this:**

```
<tr data-ng-repeat = "modules in modList | filter:filterMod">
```

**for:**

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="modules in modList | filter: { ModuleCode: searchBox }">
```

A *snippet* working:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.modList = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    $scope.modList.push({
      "ModuleCode": "Code " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1,
      "ModuleTitle": "Title " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1,
      "Semesters": "Semester " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="searchBox" placeholder="Search" class="form-control input-md" ng-keypress="test($event)" />
  <p>{{searchBox}}</p>
  <table class="table fixed-header">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center" data-ng-click="orderBy('ModuleCode')">Module Code</th>
        <th class="text-center" data-ng-click="orderBy('ModuleTitle')">Module Name</th>
        <th class="text-center" data-ng-click="orderBy('Semesters')">Semester</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr data-ng-repeat="modules in modList | filter: { ModuleCode: searchBox }">
        <td class="text-center">{{modules.ModuleCode}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{modules.ModuleTitle}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{modules.Semesters}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

I recommend you to check the [API reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) of `filter`.

I hope it helps!

Comment: i tried it before. It doesnt work too. It have an error.

Error: $parse:syntax
Syntax Error
Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 18 of the expression [modList |] starting at [{4}].

Comment: @developer333 I understand what you meant. I saw it while researching for a solution and tested it. But it just didnt filter it for me. I have no idea why too.

Comment: @YaocongTiong, I don't know why it's not working. It's working as you can see in the simple *demo* above. Can you post here how is your `array` data actually? I mean the `modList`.

Comment: I dont think. There is any error with the array data. As I  replace it with the samepl created by you and it doesn't work too.

Comment: @YaocongTiong, I noticed I missed (`:`) after `filter` keyword, it's -> `<tr data-ng-repeat="modules in modList | filter: { ModuleCode: searchBox }">`, can you check it now?

Comment: I realise it and fix it. Now there are no syntax error but it is not filtering. Like it does nothing when i try to test it.

Comment: No errors and no filter? There is something so strange.

Comment: yes, it is damn strange. I tried it the whole day ._

Comment: Can you copy here how is your `tr` tag actually? And part of the `data` that you're testing?

Comment: [{"ModuleCode":"ACC1002","ModuleTitle":"Financial Accounting","Semesters":[1,2]},{"ModuleCode":"ACC1002X","ModuleTitle":"Financial Accounting","Semesters":[1,2]},{"ModuleCode":"ACC1006","ModuleTitle":"Accounting Information Systems","Semesters":[1,2]}, ... 
This is a sample of the data i am testing. As for <tr> tag, I have already posted on top? What do you mean by how is the tr tag actually?

Comment: I mean this -> `"<tr data-ng-repeat="modules in modList...>"`

Comment: <tr data-ng-repeat="modules in modList | filter: { ModuleCode: searchBox }">
                               <td class="text-center">{{modules.ModuleCode}}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">{{modules.ModuleTitle}}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">{{modules.Semesters}}</td>
                               
                           </tr>

Comment: It really works, check it -> http://plnkr.co/edit/l9qHaLtSXJIxofzFJuzK?p=preview. Your problem isn't with the table anymore...

Comment: oh no. Then I have no idea why it is not working. From my localhost, it is not filtering base on the input

Comment: Are you sure that have no errors? Well, the solution now is: you can create a plnkr with your **complete** code, including your JS controller, view and all relevant code and I'll take a look.

Comment: I try on Plunkr and it works. I have no idea why it doesnt work on localhost

Comment: Your own plnkr? *Maybe* it can be a cache issue, try to restart your application.

Comment: @YaocongTiong, so what happens?